# Firefox unexpected behavior

Tags: firefox

Yesterday, after a fresh Windows 7 installation, I have installed Firefox 34.0.5 and then I have set, among the others, the following options:

- [X] Warn me when sites try to install add-ons: Empty (no exceptions).
- [X] Never check for updates.

Today, without any message, Firefox has forced the upgrade to the version 39.0.3.

And then, about the option **Clear all history**:

- if **Site preferences** is checked [X], Firefox restores the initial (factory set) exceptions about add-ons install;
- if **Site preferences** is unchecked [ ], the add-ons install exceptions continue to be empty (as set by me).

I would like also to add that this behavior is a bit random, because the initial (factory set) exceptions about add-ons install sometimes are restored even if **Site preferences** is unchecked. This behavior is only with the 39.0.3 version. All previous versions worked well.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is for programming questions. It's not a technical support forum for software you've installed. Please take our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an idea of what this site is about and what kinds of questions are typically asked here.

Comment: Thanks, I take your comment in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Can maybe answer the first part of your question:

Firefox issued [this warning](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/08/06/firefox-exploit-found-in-the-wild/) and urged users to update to 39.0.3

Firefox also updates the browser when you check "About Firefox" - even if you turn off automatic updates - [see here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version#Configuring_update_options)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of that security warning. Usually, the **About** window has a **Check for updates** button to check manually. I would like to choose if an update will be done or not. I don't want the software takes the control. If this is the new Firefox behavior, will be necessary to find an alternative.